# define a common template c++ class for arithmetic types and pointers

Tags: c++11, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I need to define a common template class for arithmetic types and pointer types.

following is the code I tried but I never got it correct. I need to implement it using g++4.4.7, because of that I am using boost.

The output should be ARITHMETIC followed by POINTER.

```
//primary template class
template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct Class
{
};


template <class C>
struct Class<C, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_arithmetic<C>::value || boost::is_pointer<C>::value>::type>
{
  static inline typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_arithmetic<C>::value, void>::type
  print(const C& obj)
  {
    std::cout << "ARITHMETIC TYPE" << std::endl;
  }

  static inline typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_pointer<C>::value, void>::type
  print(const C& obj)
  {
    Class<uint64_t>::print(reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t&>(obj));
    std::cout << "POINTER" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  Class<int*>::print(&x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: SFINAE doesn't work on non-templates like `print`. If you want to use SFINAE, you'd have to make `print` a template. There are other possible techniques, e.g. tag dispatch.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the hint. I made print a template function and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I made print a template function and it is working as expected.

```
template <class C>
struct Class<C, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_arithmetic<C>::value || boost::is_pointer<C>::value>::type>
{
  template <class T>
  static inline typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<C, T>::value && boost::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type
  print(const T& obj)
  {
    std::cout << "ARITHMETIC TYPE" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class T>
  static inline typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<C, T>::value && boost::is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type
  print(const T& obj)
  {
    Class<uint64_t>::print(reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t&>(obj));
    std::cout << "POINTER" << std::endl;
  }
};
```